# Keep pixel resolution when creating an image array with montage in Matlab

Tags: matlab, resolution, montage

I am trying to create an image array, combining ~80 .jpg images in a single row using the function *montage* in Matlab.

The final figure displays my images in a row, however the resolution is reduced so the 'individual' images aren't clearly visible anymore.

Is there a way to increase the resolution of the final figure or to maintain the number of pixels of each individual image added to the row?

Thanks for your help.

```
myFolder = %(folder containing .jpg images);
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpgFiles = dir(filePattern);
fileNames = string({jpgFiles.name});
ICE = montage(fileNames, 'size', [1 NaN]);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ThumbnailSize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html#d120e196455) property is what you are looking for. Use the following and images will be shown with their original resolutions:

```
ICE = montage(fileNames, 'size', [1 NaN], 'ThumbnailSize', []);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I resolved my issue by creating a 1D cell array and using functions imread and imwrite.